# hibernate: update a column based on another

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a table with 2 main columns: name and name without accent.
I would like hibernate to update the 2nd one when 1st one is changed:

```
@Column(name = "name")
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String s) {
    this.name = s;
    this.noAccentName = RemoveDiacritics(name);  //remove diacritics from name
}

@Column(name = "noaccent_name")
public String getNoAccentName() {
    return this.noAccentName;
}

public void setNoAccentName(String s) {
    this.noAccentName = s;
}
```

This is working but it has an overhead: setter of the name sets object to dirty, and hibernate wants to update it all the time... :(

How can I ask hibernate to update 'noAccentName' when 'name' was changed in a clean way?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You found the Interceptor, but as of Hibernate 4 the recommended way of doing things like this is to use [Callback methods](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html).  In fact, I can't find interceptors in Hibernate 4 at all, so you might not have an upgrade path if you go that way.

I believe what you want to do is this:

```
@Column(name = "name")
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String s) {
    this.name = s;
}

@PrePersist
private void updateNoAccentName() {
    this.noAccentName = RemoveDiacritics(this.name);
}

@Column(name = "noaccent_name")
public String getNoAccentName() {
    return this.noAccentName;
}

private void setNoAccentName(String s) {
    this.noAccentName = s;
}
```

Hibernate will then take responsibility for updating the noAccentName just before saving the object.  Note that I also made the setNoAccentName method private, as there is no way to convert from noAccentName to name and get the accents right.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Simple and clean. 
And it works. :)

I use @ PreUpdate + @ PrePersist (for update and for insert)

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution. :) Its name is hibernate interceptor.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html

With the help of a simple interceptor i can update noAccent field based on another.

Thanks your time and effort,

Comment: I agree, this *might* be the best solution.  You should also think about using @Neil's answer, since that code is in your getters and setters and easier for developers to see and understand.

Answer (score 0):

Can you always derive noAccentName given the value of name?  If so, you should label it and the getter and setters `@Transient` so that they will no longer be affected by hibernate.  Just set the value of noAccentName whenever name is set and hibernate won't update that particular instance unless the value of name changes.

**Edit:**
Alternatively you could try checking equality of the name with respect to the new one being assigned, so you don't assign any fields unless strictly necessary (which would cause hibernate to mark it as dirty).  If it *still* updates, it's either because hibernate is configured to update regardless or because another field is being updated as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i want noAccentName to be updated in db. And yes: noAccentName is always derived from name.

Problem with my solution: only when i load 10 rows from table, this causes an update (because hibernate thinks that they were changed).

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is using field access instead of property access, maybe even just for those two properties (see [access type](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e535), not recommended).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a domain naming issue here. You're not just setting the name when you call setName at this point. Another method like changeName that changes the value of both seems more appropriate. Although I would agree with Neil that if the value is always derived then you have little value in persisting both the name and the altered name. If you're application is the only one using the information, why not drop the column and just provide a separate accessor that removes the diacricitals.

Comment: You have right: it would be cleaner to drop that column.
But it is a feature in our application: when user types without diacritics, search (and autocomplete, etc) will give diacritical hits as well.

Comment: Does your DB not allow searching without respect to Diacritical characters?

Comment: This is the basic question. :)
We've tried to use a custom index with removed diacritics, but it had performance problems: db made many times bad planning (and slow queries). PostgreSQL 9.1.3